# Webstorm SCSS File Watcher does not respect parent directory

Tags: sass, phpstorm, webstorm

My scss has the following structure:

Nested directory view:

```
style
  sass
    components
      _somecomponent.scss
      _someothercomponent.scss
    style.scss
  style.css
```

Collapsed directory view:

```
style/style.css
style/sass/style.scss
style/sass/components/_somecomponent.scss
style/sass/components/_someothercomponent.scss
```

`style.scss` includes `_somecomponent.scss` and `_someothercomponent.scss`, and is supposed to generate `style.css`. It does all of this correctly, but the output file is not in the correct directory. Currently it outputs to `style/sass/style.css`.

Webstorm is configured with the following parameters:

```
Program: /usr/bin/sass
Arguments: --no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
Working directory: $FileDir$
Output path: $FileParentDir$\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

The `phpstorm` tag has been added because it shares the same file watcher with `webstorm`. I am using Mac OS X, with the latest Webstorm 9.x.

How do I fix the output path?

Comment: The `Output path` field is for IDE to look for the changed files and group/nest generated files under source file -- [it does not affect generated file location at all](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/new-watcher-dialog.html?search=file%20watchers#immediateFileSynchronization). I'm not working with SCSS myself .. but based on parameters you need to update your `Arguments` field -- it should be  similar to this: `--no-cache --update $FileName$:../$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` (you may try `$FileParentDir$` instead of `..`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please change the Arguments field accordingly:

```
    Program: /usr/bin/sass
    Arguments: --no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileParentDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
    Working directory: $FileDir$
    Output path: $FileParentDir$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

The 'Output paths to refresh' option doesn't tell the compiler where to put the generated files - you have to set the program arguments accordingly; 'Output paths' is used by IDE to synchronize its file system with external changes - you need to make sure that the pattern specified there matches the actual compiler output so that the IDE knows where to look for generated files.
So you need to modify BOTH 'Arguments' and 'Output path to refresh' options to have the generated files created in non-default location.

Comment: Ah, that indeed solved my issue! But if these two are always the same... why are they different options? In other words, why would you want different refresh and output paths?

Comment: Because a file watcher is just a generic way to assign external program that has a CLI as a listener to file change events. Programs have different arguments in different formats, so WebStorm has no way to 'parse' arguments fields and set up 'Output paths' accordingly. And vice versa - even if the desired output path is known to WebStorm (via 'Output paths to refresh' value), it can't update the Arguments field accordingly, as it isn't aware of the expected options/formats. So, in short: 'Output paths to refresh' option is for IDE, and 'Arguments' - for the program being run as a watcher