# How to write custom output path in PhpStorm file watcher

Tags: phpstorm

My scss file is in `project/repo/style/home/index.scss` and want save compiled css file in `project/repo/dist/style/home/index.css` but can not find any good solution.

How to do that?

Comment: Have a look at this comment/thread, for example: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206347569/comments/207385679

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096157/webstorm-scss-file-watcher-does-not-respect-parent-directory/29096837#29096837

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found answer:
after install ruby and sass need restart system.

Webstorm is configured with the following parameters:

```
Program: /usr/bin/sass
Arguments: --no-cache --style compressed --update --sourcemap=none $FileName$:$ProjectFileDir$/repo/Style/$FileDirPathFromParent(Style)$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css
Working directory: $FileDir$
Output path:$ProjectFileDir$/repo/Style/$FileDirPathFromParent(Style)$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Comment: --style compressed set minify & --sourcemap=none disable source map. can remove.